How to get a specific value in a reference cell?
Sorry I'm new to this.
What I'm trying to do is get a specific value from cell "G2" = TRUE
so that the ui would pop up.
I don't know what function to use.
I could use some help.
Thank you in advance!
Current script
I don't know what function to use.

Actual script should be pasted into post and formatted as script.  Screenshots make it difficult for someone to help you since they cannot be copied and pasted into a script editor for testing purposes.

if(sheet.getRange("G2") == "TRUE") { SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("G2 is true");} You can also  use checkboxes to set the value between "FALSE" and "TRUE"

If you want to check if G2 is true every time the value changes, you should use the reserved function onEdit(e).
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getSheetName() == 'Inventory'){
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'G2' && e.range.getValue() == true){
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      var response = ui.alert('G2 is true', 'Do you wish to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)

      if (response == ui.Button.YES){
        // YES WAS PRESSED
      }
    }
  }
}

otherwise, you just need to change this line:
if (shUserForm.getRange("G2").isValue(10) == true)

// CHANGE TO
if (shUserForm.getRange("G2").getValue() == true) 

